# How to 'save' progress whilst web scraping in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping some data and making a lot of requests from Reddit's pushshift API, along the way I keep encountering http errors, which halt all the progress, is there any way in which I can continue where I left off if an error occurs?

```
X = []
for i in ticklist: 
    f = urlopen("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?q={tick}&subreddit=wallstreetbets&metadata=true&size=0&after=1610928000&before=1613088000".format(tick=i))
    j = json.load(f)
    subs = j['metadata']['total_results']
    X.append(subs)
    print('{tick} has been scraped!'.format(tick=i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

I've so far mitigated the 429 error by waiting for a second in between requests - although I am experiencing connection time outs, I'm not sure how to efficiently proceed with this without wasting a lot of my time rerunning the code and hoping for the best.

Comment: It depends how you design your flow, simple store failed links in a list and loop until it's cleared.

Comment: @TấnNguyên Sorry I am a bit confused by what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: Push your request in your try catch, when it got error it would throw the Exception. From exception, you have to save error information (such as ticket number) to anywhere, file or list, then after a while check if the list is not empty, then fire recrawl these links.

Answer (score 0):

Python sqlitedb approach: Refrence: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm

Create sqlitedb.

- Create a table with urls to be **scraped** with schema like CREATE TABLE COMPANY (url NOT NULL UNIQUE, Status NOT NULL default "Not started")
- Now read the rows only for which the status is "Not started".
- you can change the status column of the URL to success once scraping is done.
- So wherever the script starts it will only run run for the not started once.